# Dataset Update Filter Location

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7

This has always bugged me to what is the best way to do the following...

with a simple one to many db, when you have 2 tables/grids on a form and the 2nd one filtered by the first.

where is the best place to put the filter code
ie:

```
procedure TForm1.tblCustormersAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if tblCustormersCustormerID.AsString <> '' then
   begin
     tblCustormersThings.Filter := 'CustormerID = ' + tblCustormersCustormerID.AsString;
     tblCustormersThings.Filtered := true;
   end;
end;
```

AfterScroll seems to work most of the time, but donst get fired on some events eg after posting. Normally i would have a procedure to do the filter update and put it where ever it seems to be needed.

But i was wondering if there is a better way, this seems like simply stuff delphi should know about...

I Dont think it matters but im Using Delphi7 and NexusDB1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set **MasterSource** and master fields properties on "many" side.

It is called Master - Detail relationship, and you should check with NexusDB help for a way to crate this relation ship between tables.

If your table supports indexes, than you can create index on **CustomerID** and also use **SetRange()** method.

The way you set Filter is the slowest one.

Comment: I knew there had to be a better way, Nexusdb tables are descended from Tdataset so the MasterSource and MasterFields where there, I just had to fix up some of the indexs. Thankyou